# What does $\exists x:\top$ mean?

Tags: logic

Does it mean that something exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the language has the symbols $\top$ (*verum*) and $\bot$ (*falsum*), they are $0$-ary *conncetives* and thus also formulas.

If so, the definition of *formula* is [see: Dirk van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&pg=PA57) (5th ed - 2013), page 57]:

> **Definition 3.3.2** FORM [the set of formulas] is the smallest set $X$ with the properties:
>
> > (i) $\bot$ [$\top $ is simply $\lnot \bot$] $\in X$;
> >
> > [...]
> >
> > (iv) if $\varphi \in X$, then $((∀x) \varphi), ((∃x) \varphi) \in X$.

---

$\top$ is always true; thus, also $(\exists x) \top$ is always true.

---

In general, the syntax of FOL does not prevent from quantifying a variable that is not present in the subformula in the scope of the quantifier.

A formula like e.g. $\exists x \ (0=0)$ is "legal"; of course, its meaning is nothing more than: $0=0$.